# Don't understand how Codility CountDiv solution is correct

Tags: c, algorithm

[Codility CountDiv Exercise](https://codility.com/programmers/task/count_div/):

Given a range A..B and value K, return the number of values in the range that are divisible by K.

The example given is A = 6, B = 11 and K = 2. In the range 6 to 11, the numbers divisible by 2 are 6, 8 and 10, so the answer is 3. The solution required must be O(1) - so a simple calculation is needed.

You can assume that A and B are in the range 0..2,000,000,000, K is 1..2,000,000,000 and that 0 <= A <= B.

The accepted solution, that scores 100% is as follows:

```
int solution(int A, int B, int K)
{
    int inclusive = ((A%K)==0) ? 1 : 0;
    return (B/K) - (A/K) + inclusive;
}
```

Where I get confused is that when I test this solution with inputs A=0, B=0 and K=1, the result is 1? I would have thought that in the range 0 to 0, the number of values divisible by 1 is... 0!

I thought this was an error and that the +1 for inclusive values of A should only be set if A is non-zero.

So I submitted the following solution (test that A is non-zero):

```
int solution(int A, int B, int K)
{
    int inclusive = (A && (A%K)==0) ? 1 : 0;
    return (B/K) - (A/K) + inclusive;
}
```

But this only scored 62% (50% correctness and 75% performance). Some of the  test cases it failed were:

- A = 0, B = 1, K = 11 - Got 0, expected 1
- A = 0, B = MAXINT, K in {1,MAXINT}, got 2000000000, expected 2000000001

Can someone explain?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The value `0` is divisible by `K` for all `K` that are allowed (non zero). There is nothing special about zero. The definition of divisible means there is no remainder after dividing.

Answer (score 9):

The range is inclusive: there is 1 value in the range `0` to `0`: the value `0` itself.  All values are divisible by `1`, so the result is indeed `1` value.

Note that the proposed code is redundant:

`int inclusive = ((A%K)==0) ? 1 : 0;` is equivalent to `int inclusive = (A%K)==0;`.  It can be further simplified as `int inclusive = !(A%K);` and the complete solution becomes a one-liner:

```
int solution(int A, int B, int K) { return B/K - A/K + !(A%K); }
```

And here is a variant with only 2 divisions:

```
int solution(int A, int B, int K) { return B/K - (A ? (A-1)/K : -1); }
```

Comment: You seem knowledgeable about this. Do you maybe know what this task has to do with PrefixSums? I see no usage of Prefix Sums here...

Comment: @MartinBerger it is indeed a prefix sum problem. I have put explanation on my code here, please have a look: https://app.codility.com/demo/results/trainingW92E84-XPZ/

Answer (score 6):

Here is a C++ solution with 100/100 score

```
int solution(int A, int B, int K) {
    return B / K - A / K + (A % K == 0 ? 1 : 0);
}
```

it returns the number of multiples in the interval [0, B] minus the number of multiples in the interval [0, A] - getting the number of multiples in the interval (A, B] - and adds the multiple in A if A is a multiple.

Comment: This is brilliant

Comment: this doesn't answer the question "Can someone explain?"

Answer (score -3):

In my case, I just made the following math:

**(B - A)/K + (A/K)**

in same cases as explained before, this + (A/K) is very tricky because of some stupid inputs like A=0,B=0 etc. Then, for those cases, I made a treatment, and I'm calling it of adjustment.

There's the code:

```
class Solution {
public int solution(int startingFrom, int endingAt, int divisibleBy) {

    double adjustment = startingFrom % divisibleBy == 0 || endingAt % divisibleBy == 0 ? 1 : ((double) startingFrom < divisibleBy) ? (double) startingFrom / divisibleBy : 0;

    return (int) ( ((double) endingAt - startingFrom) / (divisibleBy) + adjustment);
}
```

}

Java code 100/100.

https://app.codility.com/demo/results/trainingS96J5R-NTC/

Comment: this doesn't answer the question "Can someone explain?"